# Padding changes whole layout with z-index

Tags: css, formatting, z-index, padding

This may seem like really easy fix for most but I think I have been staring at this for too long now. I have googled and searched all through Stack but can't find a similar question/answer.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufMD5/1/

The format is exactly how I want it apart from wanting padding in the `.emailAlert` div. As soon as I add padding (remove comment marks from fiddle) the `.form` div moves down the page. I just want the `.form` div to stay where it is!

By the way, I want to thank all the top coders out there who take time to answer questions on Stack. We all need help sometimes and us amateurs are lucky to have your help so readily available, despite how stupid our questions may be!

**EDIT:**

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufMD5/11/ I replaced the width values with the ones I am actually using and the problem is there in this fiddle. I am using chrome v32.

Comment: In what browser? I can't replicate the problem. Tested in: FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera

Comment: yes!!! not able to replicate the prob

Comment: I use chrome for my testing. The fiddle in Chrome shows exactly what is wrong

Comment: As stated, Chrome was tested and the votes on my comment along with Wizard indicates that others cannot replicate the problem. You could expand your question with screenshots of the problem, and the exact version of Chrome. Hopefully you're on a version of Chrome 32?

Comment: added new fiddle with proper values. Problem is now definitely replicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you edited your answer:

Problem is that adding padding results in a wider element, and hence your pop-up can't be allocated close to your text. The two of them together are wider than the container.

Change position to static on your pop-up to see the problem.

To fix it again I would use `position:absolute` for your pop out.

Just did that little change (obviously modify left and top properties accordingly) and it worked:

```
.emailAlert {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 150px;
    background: #FFD;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: #999 1px dashed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Also removed `float:left` since we are using absolute positioning.

Comment: You mean you could actually duplicate the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the new fiddle, there is not enough room to the right of the .form to display the email alert. The form is 650px wide, the email alert 320px if you include the padding, and the container 960px. It just doesn't fit.

If you remove the relative positioning, you can see what happens much more clearly. The email alert is a floating block, and the form moves to below it, where there's room.

Solution: make the container wide enough.